# Predict the probability that a customer buy today

Tags: forecasting

My company sells a single product that is a commodity. If you buy it, I can be sure that you will buy it again in the near future **from me or from my competitors**. The demand is affected by the weather. If we have high temperatures my product sales decrease, and vice-versa.

I have this data per sale:

- Customer
- Average temperature in the day of the sale
- Amount of product bought in a transaction
- Size of the customer warehouse
- Price at the moment of the purchase
- Timestamp of the sale

The problem:

I want, based on historic time series data, to get the Probability that a customer requires my product today. I would like to have a %. Customer X have a 70% of probability of require your product today based on the historic. With that I could get a list of all the customers that today have 80% or more probability of buying and take action with that.

The complexities I see:

- I have a lot of data because I have a lot of customers but for a single customer I have an average of only 5 purchases.
- If the customer is not loyal and gets the product from my competitors I have holes that make sales separated by a irregular time spans.

**What would be a good algorithm to tackle this problem?**

I thought about regressions using time series but I won't get a probability. Maybe transform the timestamp of re-purchase per customer in my training set and try to cluster based on days between purchases.

Answer (score 0):

You could frame the problem as survival analysis - predict the probability of an event during a certain time period.

The data quality issues will affect the modeling. You have to decide whether you are fitting a model per customer or a model for groups of customers. Missing data will have to be ignored, explicitly modeling, dropped, or imputed.